# ASP VB.Net Trying to highlight a cell from a gridview if it is empty. but i have both a Label and a Textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here is my aspx gridview code:

```
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Interest Rate/Range" SortExpression="InterestRateRange"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbInterestRateRange" runat="server" style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: small; text-align: right;"  Text='<%# Bind("InterestRateRange")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblInterestRateRange" runat="server" Text='<%# If(Eval("InterestRateRange").ToString() Is DBNull.Value, "0 value", Eval("InterestRateRange"))%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
```

.vb code :

```
Sub HighlightGridViewRows(curGV As GridView)

    For Each row As GridViewRow In curGV.Rows 
        Dim strInterestRate As String = CType(row.Cells(5).FindControl("InterestRateRange"), TextBox).Text
' ^HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERRORS^

        'Other highlighting code is here that is for other cells that work (numerics)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strInterestRate) Then
            row.Cells(5).BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
        Else
            row.Cells(5).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

THe above line is where i get the ***System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*** error.  But i have also had issues once i got past this and it would occur when i entered edit mode and clicked update it would then say "cannot convert Textbox to Label" or vice versa depending on what i had at the time of testing.

I have tried a few other solutions i could find out there most of them lead me back to where i started just in a different way but same error.

The HighlightGridViewRows() function is called at the end of my RowDataBound sections (i have several in this case)

So how can i check to see if this cell is empty and then highlight it accordingly i seem to be going in circles?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with many changes i stumbled upon my solution (which i did try before but mis-referenced my label IDs so it didnt work) i now have the following in my vb code behind with the following if statement:

```
        If Not row.Cells(5).FindControl("lblInterestRateRange") Is Nothing Then

            Dim strInterestRate As String = CType(row.Cells(5).FindControl("lblInterestRateRange"), Label).Text
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strInterestRate) Then
                row.Cells(5).BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
            Else
                row.Cells(5).BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End If
```

Hope this helps someone else who has similar needs